# If one email is on one list it, the email is not being added to both. What is the PHP code (ifelse) for adding user to mailing list using mc4wp?

Tags: php, mailchimp

I'm trying to add one email on 2 mailing lists using MC4WP. If the email already exists on one list, it is not being added to the other one at all. 
Is there an 'else if' function to add the user in the missing mailing list regardless?

```
$mailchimp=new MC4WP_MailChimp();
$data=$mailchimp->list_subscribe("xxxxxx1",$email);
$mailchimp1=new MC4WP_MailChimp();
$data=$mailchimp1->list_subscribe("xxxxxx2",$email);
```

Comment: There's no `if` here, it adds the email to both lists unconditionally.

Comment: But you're overwriting the `$data` variable, so it only contains the result of the second call.